# Difficulty with tile background for a windows phone 7 app

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am trying to set a background for my app's tile using these [instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462080%28VS.92%29.aspx). However, it still shows the default spiky circle image. (I think it's "ApplicationIcon.png".)

Here is my `WMAppManifest.xml`:

```
<Tokens>
  <PrimaryToken TokenID="MyAppToken" TaskName="_default">
    <TemplateType5>
      <BackgroundImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">s.png</BackgroundImageURI>
      <Count>0</Count>
      <Title>My App Title</Title>
    </TemplateType5>
  </PrimaryToken>
</Tokens>
```

What could I be doing wrong? `s.png` is set to build action "Content".

Answer (score 2):

There are two icon files. They default to ApplicationIcon.png and Background.png

ApplicationIcon is 62x62, can't be transparent and is used it the list view of applications.
Background, which is what you are setting here should be 173x173, can be transparent, and it used when you pin the application to the start screen.

So my first suggestion would be to check you are actually setting the image you think you are and are looking at the start screen not the list view.

My second would be to check the image sizes are correct. I do not know what the phone does if they are not.

My third would be to check the image you are referencing is in the top level of the project, not in a folder, and is actually making it into your xap. Go into the bin\debug or bin\release then open the .xap file with a zip client and make sure it is there.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes WP7 seems to cache the old image - so my advice would be:

- if you are using the phone, then remove your app (using press and hold to bring up the menu)
- if you are using the emulator, then reboot it to ensure the app is completely removed